# Ruby on rails, Form buttons get their routes mixed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

While making a form in Ruby on Rails I encoutered something peculiar, My `submit` button performs the action of another button in the form.

```
<%=form_for(happening) do |f|%>
   <%=f.text_field :name, class:"updateInput" %>
   <%=f.submit "Save", class:"editButton" %>
   <%= button_to "Delete", happening, method: :delete, class:"editButton"%>
   <input type="datetime-local" value="<%= happening.get_html_date %>">
<%end%>
```

When I click the `submit` button in this form, it will be routed to the `destroy` action, rather than the `update` one.
When I remove the `delete`button, everything is routed properly.

Does someone have an explination for this? Thanks

Comment: Just remove the delete button outside of your form.

Comment: Or you can change the `button_to` to `link_to`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because there's more than meets the eye when you use the `button_to` helper. `button_to` doesn't just create a button -- it actually creates an entire form, with the actual button serving as the form's submit button.

By including your `button_to` helper within a form, you're violating HTML's "no nested forms" rule and effectively adding a second submit button for your form which overrides the intended submit button. There's a difference between a submit button and an input of type button in HTML, and as I mentioned already, `button_to` creates a submit button.

If you move that `button_to` outside of your form as Ahmad pointed out, you'll have un-nested your forms and your view should behave as expected.

Consult the [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

Your delete button should be outside your form.

```
<%=form_for(happening) do |f|%>
   <%=f.text_field :name, class:"updateInput" %>
   <%=f.submit "Save", class:"editButton" %>
   <input type="datetime-local" value="<%= happening.get_html_date %>">
<%end%>

<%= button_to "Delete", happening, method: :delete, class:"editButton"%>
```